# Why can't I make a table using gtsummary?

Tags: datatable, gtsummary

I'm quite new to R, just been using it for the past month or so for my master's thesis. I finally (hopefully) have figured out my model and now i'm trying to present it in a table. After some research, everyone seems to really love the gtsummary package and I really want to learn to use it. But for some reason, the most basic function is not working for me.

Here's my lmer model:

```
res1 <- lmer(pH ~ Species * SedLayer + (+1|Site), data = data 
summary(res1)
Anores1 <- Anova(res1)
Anores1
```

Which gives me quite a lot of output, [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1RN.png) [data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlUHT.png). And here's the basic code i'm trying to use:

```r
lmer(pH ~ SedLayer * Species + (+1|Site), data = dat)
#> Error in lmer(pH ~ SedLayer * Species + (+1 | Site), data = dat): could not find function "lmer"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

And I keep getting the following error message:

> Error in match.call() : ... used in a situation where it does not exist

I've got all the following packages installed and loaded:

```
library(stats)
library(rstatix)
library(car)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library("gtsummary") 
library("gt") 
library("broom.mixed")
library(tidyverse)
```

I'm sure I must be making a very silly mistake, but I cannot figure it out! Is my model somehow too weird to put in a table? Is there an additional package I should load? Or am I just writing it wrong?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Can you please update your example with data and code we can run on our machines? For example, you could use the `sleepstudy` data frame that is included in the lme4 package. This code, for example, runs fine on my machine, `lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy) %>% tbl_regression()`

Comment: Here's a short guide on creating minimal reproducible examples https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment! I used the sleepstudy data and ran the code as you wrote it above, but I still get the same error message as with my data:

"Error in match.call() : ... used in a situation where it does not exist"

I don't know what to do, if there's any setting I should change...

Comment: Can you put the code into a proper reprex and update your post with the results? https://reprex.tidyverse.org/

1. Install the reprex package, 2. Copy the gtsummary code onto your clipboard, 3. Run `reprex::reprex()`. 4. The results will copied to your clipboard, and paste them here.

Comment: I hope I did this right:

lmer(pH ~ Species * SedLayer + (+1|Site), data = dat) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE)
#> Error in lmer(pH ~ Species * SedLayer + (+1 | Site), data = dat) %>% tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE): could not find function "%>%"

Comment: It's close. You need to include the library calls in the reprex. Be sure to review the link. They have detailed instructions there.

Comment: And you'll need to update you're original post. The comments section can't render the results properly

Comment: Ok, i think this should work now, i've updated the post

Comment: Hi MF, it looks like you're having trouble creating the proper reprex. This post has more explicit details on how to do it. https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html I know being new to R is difficult, and creating a reprex may not feel straightforward. But it's pretty much the only way we can help you out.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for your patience these past few days. I have no idea what happened but before running the reprex() function, I tried running the code again and this time it worked... I haven't changed a thing since yesterday except deleting the lmerTest package from my markdown file. The reprex seems to have worked as well this time, even though I used the same method as yesterday. So I don't understand why but it worked! Thanks again for being so willing to help, it would be impossible for me to use R without people like you answering questions!